# When predicting on a single sentence, receive the error "Number of features of the model must match the input."

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm a data science newbie and I'm trying to use TfidfVectorizer with RandomForestClassifier to predict a binary "yes/no" outcome on a string like so:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('~/Downloads/New_Query_2019_12_04.csv', usecols=['statement', 'result'])
df = df.head(100)

# remove non-values
df = df.dropna()

tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(
    max_features=1500,
    min_df=5,
    max_df=0.7,
    stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))

X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(df['statement']).toarray()
y = df['result'].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X,
    y,
    test_size=0.2,
    random_state=0)

classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000, random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

All of this appears to work great, but I'm stuck on how to predict a phrase against the model. When I do something like:

```
good_string = preprocess_string('This is a good sentence')

tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer()

X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform([good_string]).toarray()

y_pred = classifier.predict(X)
```

I get the error "Number of features of the model must match the input."

I also tried fitting the string with my previous TfidfVectorizer:

```
tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(
    max_features=1500,
    min_df=5,
    max_df=0.7,
    stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))

X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform([good_string]).toarray()
```

but I got the error "max_df corresponds to < documents than min_df". I think I'm just a bit confused as to how to fit the array features of the single string to match the number features in my model. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was running it through a different vectorizer with the same constructor params:

```
tfidfconverter = TfidfVectorizer(
max_features=1500,
min_df=5,
max_df=0.7,
stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
```

instead of using the same vectorizer I used when fitting the documents here:

```
X = tfidfconverter.fit_transform(df['statement']).toarray()
```

I also should not have been attempting to fit the data I was trying to predict, but ONLY transform it.

```
X = tfidfconverter.transform([good_string]).toarray()
```